# Дата и время пакета java.util.Calendar

Tags: java

Добрый день! Сделал такое вот задание. Создать приложение, выводящее фамилию разработчика, дату и время получения задания, а также дату и время сдачи задания. Для получения последней даты и времени использовать класс Calendar из пакета java.util.

Написал так:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test{
    public static void main (String args []){

        String s = "Василевса";
        Date d = new Date();
        System.out.println("Получения задания для " + s + " " + d);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR,2011);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.JUNE);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,30);

        System.out.println("Сдача задания для " + s + " " + c.getTime());
    }
}
```

Выводит результат:

> Получения задания для Василевса Mon May 23 19:26:42 BDT 2011
>
> Сдача задания для Василевса Thu Jun 30 19:26:42 BDT 2011

1. Как можно переделать или добавить, чтоб выводило другое время, где написано Сдача задания выводит время 19:26:42, а нужно поменять на другое время.
2. Еще хотелось чтоб результат выводил на русском языке безвремени минут и секунд.

Например бы так:

> Получения задания для Василевса Понедельник Май 23 2011 или Понедельник 23 мая 2011 или Понедельник 23.05.2011
>
> Сдача задания для Василевса Среда Июнь 30 2011 или Среда 30 июня 2011 или Среда 30.06.2011

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) с конструктором, указывающим локаль: [SimpleDateFormat(pattern, locale)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale))

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.GERMANY);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(c.getTime()));

    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.getDefault());
    System.out.println(sdf2.format(c.getTime()));
```

На выходе:

```
Donnerstag
четверг
```

**UPD**

И да, есть ещё альтернативный путь: вы можете указать эту локаль самому календарю:

```
calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.GERMANY)
```

Но это менее удобно на практике, но иногда полезно

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ попробую сделать!!!